# Paramiko equvalent of pipeline controls and input/output pipes

Tags: python, file, transfer, paramiko

I need a method of paramiko based file transfer with a lightweight [SSH2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH2) server ([dropbear](http://matt.ucc.asn.au/dropbear/dropbear.html)) which has no support for [SCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scp) or [SFTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_file_transfer_protocol). Is there a way of achieving a cat and redirect style file transfer, such as:

```
ssh server "cat remote_file" > local_file
```

with [paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/) channels?

Can paramiko.Transport.open_channel() or Message() do the job? I am unsure of how to proceed.

Answer (score 3):

The following may be useful as a starting point (e.g. ./sshpipe host "command"):

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import sys
import paramiko

def sshpipe(host, line) :
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    client.connect(host)
    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(line)
    output = stdout.read()
    sys.stdout.write(output)
    stdin.close()
    stdout.close()
    stderr.close()
    client.close()

sshpipe(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
```