# How to redirect output of ssh.exec_command to a file in Python paramiko module?

Tags: python, linux, remote-access, paramiko

I want to run a python script say `test.py` on a Linux target machine (which has a python interpreter) and capture the output of the command in a text file as the part of another python script `invoke.py` using `paramiko` module.

The statement in the script

`stdin, stdout, sterr = ssh.exec_command("python invoke.py > log.txt")`

generates a **blank** file log.txt.

Please suggest corrections / alternate way to do this. to write the output to the file correctly.

`test.py` when run locally outputs sane text (which is expected to be logged in log.txt).

There are some relevant posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13509955/paramiko-exec-command-redirect-to-a-file) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133326/paramiko-equvalent-of-pipeline-controls-and-input-output-pipes), but no one deals with output of python script

Answer (score 0):

instead of calling client.exec_command() you can use client.open_channel() and use channel session's recv() and recv_stderr() streams to read write stdout/std err:

```
def sshExecute(hostname, username, password, command, logpath = None):

    buffSize = 2048
    port = 22

    client = paramiko.Transport((hostname, port))
    client.connect(username=username, password=password)

    if logpath == None:
        logpath = "./"

    timestamp = int(time.time())
    hostname_prefix = "host-%s-%s"%(hostname.replace(".","-"),timestamp)         
    stdout_data_filename = os.path.join(logpath,"%s.out"%(hostname_prefix))
    stderr_data_filename = os.path.join(logpath,"%s.err"%(hostname_prefix))    
    stdout_data = open(stdout_data_filename,"w") 
    stderr_data = open(stderr_data_filename,"w") 

    sshSession = client.open_channel(kind='session')
    sshSession.exec_command(command)
    while True:
        if sshSession.recv_ready():
            stdout_data.write(sshSession.recv(buffSize))
        if sshSession.recv_stderr_ready():
            stderr_data.write(sshSession.recv_stderr(buffSize))
        if sshSession.exit_status_ready():
            break

    stdout_data.close()
    stderr_data.close()
    sshSession.close()
    client.close()

    return sshSession.recv_exit_status()
```

Hope this fully working function helps you